# Pandas groupby and aggregate over multiple lists

Tags: pandas, list, aggregate, pandas-groupby, average

I have a data frame df, with two columns. I want to groupby one column and aggregate the lists that belong to same group by getting an "average list" (all lists elements averaged) as follows:

```
column_a, column_b
1,         [1,2,3]
1,         [2,5,1]
2,         [5,6,6]
3,         [2,0,1]
3,         [4,2,3]
```

The lists are always of the same fixed length. The desired output should be as follows:

```
group, avg_list
1,     [1.5,3.5,2]
2,     [5,6,6]
3,     [3,1,2]
```

I know I can use groupby on the dataframe and subsequently aggregate it but I'm not sure what to put in the agg part of the code.

```
df.groupby('column_a').agg(?)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the average of the lists within each group in this way:

```
s = df.groupby("column_a")["column_b"].apply(lambda x: np.array(x.tolist()).mean(axis=0))

pd.DataFrame({'group':s.index, 'avg_list':s.values})
```

Gives:

```
  group avg_list
0   1   [1.5, 3.5, 2.0]
1   2   [5.0, 6.0, 6.0]
2   3   [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I had a list of strings when I read in the data. As a result, I was receiving the error" `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type` ... so I changed from `np.array(x.tolist())` to `np.array(x.tolist()).astype(np.float)` in order to solve.

Comment: Nice! What I did  was to convert the column with `literal_eval`.This line here `df["column_b"] = df.column_b.apply(lambda s: list(ast.literal_eval(s)))`  will convert from string to list

Answer (score 0):

Group them together as a list and them use mean to find the average.

```
df.set_index('column_a')['column_b'].groupby('column_a').apply(list).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x,0))
```

Result

```
column_a
1    [1.5, 3.5, 2.0]
2    [5.0, 6.0, 6.0]
3    [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```